# Socket.io - How to prompt for username, and save the username in an array?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have got a basic chatroom which detects when users connect to the server, and leave.

Now I would like to prompt the user to enter a username when he joins the server, how can I do that?

Code is below:

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('entrance', function  (data) {
        document.write('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');

        //STORE USERNAME of NEW SOCKET
        // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
        socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
        });
    });

    socket.on('exit', function  (data) {
        document.write('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
    });

    socket.on('chat', function  (data) {
        document.write('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
  connect = require('connect');

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
var game_room = io.listen(app);

game_room.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Welcome to the chat room!'}); 
    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Your ID is #' + socket.id}); 

    socket.on('disconnect', function  () {
        game_room.sockets.emit('exit', {message: 'A chatter has disconnected.'});
    });

    socket.on('chat', function  (data) {
        game_room.socket.broadcast.emit('chat', {message: '# ' + data.message});
    });

    socket.broadcast.emit('entrance', {message: 'A new chatter is online.'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add this to your server code:

```js
var users = [];

game_room.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Welcome to the chat room!'}); 
    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Your ID is #' + socket.id}); 

    socket.on('adduser', function (name) {
       users.push(name);

       // attempt to clean up
       socket.once('disconnect', function () {
         var pos = users.indexOf(name);

         if (pos >= 0)
           users.splice(pos, 1);
       });
    });

    // ...
});
```

(it won't work if 2 users choose the same name.)

Comment: They're optional if you have only 1 statement. But feel free to add them if it makes you more comfortable.

Comment: If you don't do anything, the array will grow indefinitely, leaking memory and keeping thousands of closed sockets laying around.

Answer (score 0):

## `server.js`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('newuser', function(nick){
   var newUser = nick;
   console.log(newUser + ' connected');
   io.emit('connection2', newUser + ' connected.');
   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
     console.log('user disconnected');
     io.emit('disconnection', newUser + ' disconnected.');
   });
   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
     io.emit('chat message', msg);
   });
 });
```

## `index.html` - In the <script> tag.

```
var socket = io();

var nick = prompt('What is your desired username?');
$(function () {
  var socket = io();
  socket.emit('newuser', nick);
  // Regular forum submission event handler below this.
});
socket.on('connection2', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append($('<li style="font-style:italic;">').text(msg));
});
socket.on('disconnection', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append($('<li style="font-style:italic;">').text(msg));
});
```